# Dynamics CRM - Unregistering steps, plugins, and assembly

Tags: dynamics-crm

For testing, I have a simple DLL registered that contains a plugin. I've also registered a step after the fact.

When I retract my changes, do I need to unregister the step, the plugin, and the assembly in that order, or is unregistering the assembly good enough? I want to make sure nothing is left behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unregistering the assembly is sufficient. The system guards the referential integrity of the database. When you have unregistered the assembly all plugin types, steps and images will be removed as well.

Comment: Thank you! This will save me time in development!